# How to force gfortran to stop at First NaN?

Tags: exception, fortran, cygwin, gfortran

My Configuration: Cygwin64, Win7 64 bit, gfortran 4.8.3

I did go through all the Q/A pairs I managed to find, this one is the closest to my problem

[Force gfortran to stop program at first NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636580/force-gfortran-to-stop-program-at-first-nan)

PROBLEM: The fortran code

```
real :: init_with_NaN  ! -finit-real=nan
res = 10 * init_with_NaN
```

The code is compiled with the following gfortran flags

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-funderscoring' '-O0' '-g' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-O0' '-g' '-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow,precision,denormal' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-Wpedantic' '-std=f2003' '-fall-intrinsics' '-fbacktrace' '-fimplicit-none' '-Wextra' '-Wformat=1' '-Wconversion' '-Wfatal-errors' '-finit-real=nan' '-Wuninitialized' '-fbounds-check' '-v' '-o' 'fsignal_test.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Once the code is run, instead of getting a SIGFPE, res is set to be NaN and execution continues.

**This is a sub-problem of a million dollar question: 
Does gfortran -ffpe-trap=invalid flag really stops the program once it detects a NaN anywhere in the program ? Especially on Cygwin64 env?**

A little research showed that:

1) Acc.to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Debugging-Options.html, -ffpe-trap works **on MOST systems, not all :(**

2) Acc. to [Division by zero does not throw SIGFPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267838/division-by-zero-does-not-throw-sigfpe)

> "You don't get a signal because the default behavior on most machines
>   is to pollute your data with NaNs (not-a-number) and infinities. You
>   have to enable floating point exceptions, and how you do that is
>   machine specific. Look at the system header fenv.h, if you have one.
>   The function fesettrapenable enables catching floating point
>   exceptions on many machines.
>
> Unfortunately, there is no standard function to turn floating point
>   exceptions handling on"

3) I have checked my cygwin env, fenv.h exists in multiple places but there is no fesettrapenable function anywhere under any *.h file under cygwin64.

4) I do get SIGFPEs: like sqrt(-1), div by zero, overflow, underflow, precision

Here is the full Fortran test project in Eclipse, use it at your hearts content to learn about exceptions on your own platform:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9U1dlb_UCPqU194XzhDNTNkUUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The test project link provides you the test code to repro this situation. Look for res = 10 * init_with_NaN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force gfortran to stop program at first NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636580/force-gfortran-to-stop-program-at-first-nan)